# Android: Navigation drawer обработка нажатия на один из элементов меню

Tags: android

По Navigation Drawer пока нашел только старые уроки. Там показывается пример в основном, где есть специальна функция onNavigationItemSelected , которая обрабатывает нажатие на один из пунктов меню. Сейчас я так понял вся навигация происходит через некий NavController. 
Если же мне надо таки обработать нажатие на пункт меню для, например, открытия новой активити или еще чего, то как лучше это сдедать.

Пробовал создавать clickListener для пункта меню - выдает ошибку. Добавлял к свойству item-а onClick функию - то же выдает ошибку...